# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string( for built-in components)

Tags: react-native

React native simulator gives the error 
"Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string( for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

import SearchPage from './SearchPage';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Property Finder',
          component: SearchPage,
        }}/>
    );
}
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
  flex: 1,
},
});
```

SearchPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Button,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';;

export default class SearchPage extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.description}>
          Search for houses to buy!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.description}>
          Search by place-name or postcode.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  description: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#656565'
  },
  container: {
    padding: 30,
    marginTop: 65,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
});
```

[image: Simulator showing this when I'm running the code.]

Could someone tell the problem in it.
Using react-native version: 0.61

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I have submitted the code as please have a look above the image.

Comment: can you share the entire code in a expo snack so that we can test it?

Comment: this is what I got @GauravRoy

Comment: which is the device you run the app? android or ios

Comment: @Lenoarod I am running on ios

Comment: Kindly check once if all the imports have been done correctly. This error occurs due to this, check for reference : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16332

Answer (score 0):

the error you met often occurs when you likely forgot to export your component from the file it’s defined in. I see your code it is done.
I run your code. it shows `NavigatorIOS` is removed from the library.  and I think that it caused by `NavigatorIOS`, it is only working on ios and deprecated. you should use 'react-native-navigation`or`react-native-router-flux'  and I suggest you use  `react-native-router-flux`.
if use the `react-native-router-flux`, you can look at the following code:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Stack key="root">
      <Scene key="search" component={SearchParge} title="search" />
    </Stack>
  </Router>

// then, if you want to go to it
Actions.search()
);
```